# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'firebase.initializeApp')

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm stuck at this error. I'm beginner in react native and firebase. I just want to make a connection between react native and firebase.
Please anyone has an idea about this problem?

index.android.js

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const StatusBar = require('./components/StatusBar');
const ActionButton = require('./components/ActionButton');
const ListItem = require('./components/ListItem');
const styles = require('./styles.js')

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.intializeApp({
   apiKey: "XXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXX",
    projectId: "XXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXX"
});
```

Package.js

```js
{
  "name": "Primed_Network",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apsl-react-native-button": "^3.1.0",
    "firebase": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0"
  },
  
}
```

Comment: is this react-native-firebase?

Comment: yes i want to add user using react native and Firebase

Answer (score 1):

Try to import firebase like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```